# Dates difference wrongly stored in MySQL database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, datetime, sequelize.js

I'm facing a very weird problem regarding dates substraction (time elapsed) in Javascript (Node.js) and MySQL (managed via Sequelizejs). I HAVE debugged and did NOT find a solution yet.

Simply, I have to log when a user signs in and when they sign out and to calculate how many **seconds** (not milliseconds) they have been online.

My log table has these fields:

- created_at: **datetime**
- exited_at:  **datetime**
- time_elapsed: **decimal(10,0)**

The problem is that **datetimes are stored correctly** but time differences only the 90% of the times (**not always**). The rest, wrong values are saved. I've tried different ways to substract and none have worked.

By wrong values, I mean this (script to calculate DIFF is below):

```
- exit_at                 created_at          time_elapsed     DIFF
- 2014-03-14 09:07:19   2014-03-14 09:04:07      116           192
- 2014-03-15 12:10:06   2014-03-15 12:06:43      3             203
- 2014-03-19 16:32:19   2014-03-19 16:31:27      20            52
- 2014-03-19 20:50:45   2014-03-19 19:28:27      3321          4938
- 2014-03-19 23:55:13   2014-03-19 20:50:45      10926         11068
```

This is how, now (using moment.js), I compute time differences:

```
log.find({ where: { ... } })
.success( function(logEntry)
{
    if (logEntry)
    {
           var endDate   = moment(date);
           var startDate = moment(logEntry.updated_at);
           var diff      = endDate.diff(startDate, 'seconds');

            logEntry.updateAttributes
            ({
                exit_at: date,
                time_elapsed: diff
            })
    }
});
```

I've used console.log to watch what the results are, and they are correct but I don't know what happens after they are stored. May it be a bug in sequelizejs?

By the way, this is how I get the wrong results:

```
SELECT exitedat, createdat, time_elapsed, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, createdat, exitedat) DIFF 
FROM logs
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, createdat, exitedat) > time_elapsed;
```

Comment: I would start by checking the format of the date your sending, and the format it becomes when its in MySQL.  This is a classic problem a lot of PHP developers have when dealing with date/time math between their code and MySQL.  So my first step would be to verify that the correct data is persisting.  Also doing everything in UTC will help avoid any timezone related issues.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "wrong values" means ? Are we talking about missing seconds or what? If that is the case, you might hit MySQL's inability to store milliseconds in datetimes.

Comment: Wrong values are wrong seconds; for example, sometimes (not always), when i should have 2345 seconds, i get 100 or something like that. As I specify in the source code, I store seconds, not milliseconds --> 
var diff = endDate.diff(startDate, 'seconds');